# Failed Windows installation - "Windows could prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation"

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, windows-installation

I followed [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-make-a-windows-10-usb-using-your-mac-build-a-bootable-iso-from-your-macs-terminal/) to create a USB stick to install windows.

I've got to the point where I'm able to run the installation, several of the steps complete, but on the last step I get this error.

[image]

Before that I've tried various things with `diskpart` (clean the disk, create a new partition) that have gotten over other problems. But now I'm stumped with this.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10):

So it appears after running into this myself and finally getting some time to fight with it, that certain systems' BIOS/UEFI implementations are buggy, and if your Windows installation USB is using GPT partitions instead of MBR, the installer stupidly attempts to reconfigure the USB's EFI/System partition as the target even though it just formatted and otherwise prepared the internal drive that you selected in the install process.

The "fix" for this is to recreate your USB drive's using MBR instead of GPT.

I ran into this when creating a USB installer on a Mac (which have been using GPT and EFI for quite a while). This post helped me discover my error and recreate the USB drive properly. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-make-a-windows-10-usb-using-your-mac-build-a-bootable-iso-from-your-macs-terminal/

It is possible to convert from GPT to MBR using `sgdisk`. `sgdisk -m /dev/sda` will convert from GPT to MBR, and `sgdisk -g /dev/sda` will convert from MBR to GPT.

This long-winded Gist is how I create the Windows USB from the command line in a consistent and repeatable manner. https://gist.github.com/dragon788/26921410d8de054366188c5c5435ae01

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems like `sgdisk` is only a Linux thing? At any rate it's not available on my Mac (Monterey). But I simply did all the steps from that freecodecamp tutorial again, except this time with the MBR version of the format command. I had been seeing the same error as the OP, except in my case the installation wouldn't complete any steps. The error appeared as soon as I reached the "Installing windows" screen. But using MBR solved it.

Comment: Can confirm this was the fix for me too on a Lenovo P1 Gen 3. God bless you!

Comment: Can confirm that using MBR instead of GPT when installing Windows 11 Pro on a new SSD (Asus B450M-A II motherboard ) did the trick, thank you!

Comment: After several hours wasted with this error, the MBR route instead of GPT fixed this. Thank you thank you!!! Installing Windows 11 from Mac Ventura 13.0.1.

Comment: Can confirm that using MBR instead of GPT on the USB stick also solved the issue for me on ASUS TUF Gaming A15 (2023). I also had to reformat the USB disk with `diskutil` because there's no `sgdisk` on macOS Sonoma.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to physically pull out the USB stick after 'copying files' and 'getting files ready' were complete but before getting to 'Finishing up'. Then it continued normally.

I assume this is not normal for a USB installation of Windows!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, P14s

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect everything from the motherboard during the install, and try again.

Also, download the windows image again. It could be a bad installation image too.

Comment: Tried a different computer (Windows) to create the USB, same problem.

It's a laptop (Thinkpad T480) so tricky to pull out components.

Managed to find a solution though,

Comment: @Tom, how did you fix this? I am also getting this issue on P14s.

Comment: @Lester the only solution I found was the one I posted as an answer - something about keeping the USB stick in too long was causing the installation to fail

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate @Tom solution, then some more clarification is needed. The issue mainly occurs for incorrect BIOS configuration.

- Besides the flash drive, remove any kind of unnecessary removable media like DVD or CDs.
- Enter your BIOS and restore to default settings, or if you can, reset your BIOS.

Comment: The problem is I had to have the flash drive inserted to install Windows, but then leaving it in caused the installation to fail later on. Very unintuitive. I had already reset the BIOS